# What is "END" in this program (Python/Tkinter/Files)

Tags: python, tkinter

https://github.com/ansonallseitz/pythonDrills/blob/master/Liang/ch14/FileEditor.py

I didn't write this code, its from a textbook.

In lines 47-58 there are 2 functions. I understand everything about the functions, accept the use of "END"

I re-read the chapter and I couldn't find out what they were talking about.

```
    def openFile(self): 
        filenameforReading = askopenfilename()
        infile = open(filenameforReading, "r")
        self.text.insert(END, infile.read())  # <- this "END"
        infile.close()  # Close the input file
    
    def saveFile(self):
        filenameforWriting = asksaveasfilename()
        outfile = open(filenameforWriting, "w")
        # Write to the file
        outfile.write(self.text.get(1.0, END))  # <- and this "END"
        outfile.close() # Close the output file
```

I read the chapter, and googled.
I can't figure out what the heck is going on here.

I mean... I understand its about reading and writing files.

Comment: It comes from `tkinter`.  See the duplicate answer for details.

Comment: Don't put markup in code: if you need to call something out, use code comments. `*` and `**` are real Python syntax, if the code doesn't have those, don't put them in.

Answer (score 0):

`"1.0"` here means the start of the text, `END` or `"end"` means the end of the text.
The `.get` method asks for starting and the ending points as its arguments.

I recommend checking this: https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/text.htm

Comment: That link doesn't work.

Comment: It works if you lose the "l" from the end of the link  https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/text.htm